# Can a second derivative exist if the first derivative is undefined?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a function $y=1/(1+e^{-x})$. I have been asked to use the first derivative to find any stationary points and then use the second derivative to classify them and provide points of inflection.

When I derive the function, I get the result $e^{-x}/(1+e^{-x})^2$. By setting this function to zero, I find that the equation is undefined at that point. Am I then correct to assume that the function contains no stationary points, and that therefore I cannot classify stationary points or find points of inflection? Or have I missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the title of the question and the question itself are quite different ... The function is defined at all points, and so is its derivative, so I don't see any undefined behaviour. You merely found out that the derivative is always positive.

Comment: "the equation is undefined at that point": what ??

Comment: A critical point of $f(x)$ is any value of $c$ such that $f(c)$ is defined, and *either* $f'(c)=0$ *or* $f'(c)$ is undefined. So the latter points also need to be analysd somehow. Usually look to left and right. Note for your function the denominator is always positive as is numerator so no critical points at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first derivative is

$$\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2},$$ which has no roots. Hence there are no stationary points.

The second derivative is

$$\frac{e^{-2x}-e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^3},$$ which has a single root at $x=0$. Hence there is an inflection point.

Comment: So when f'(x) is equal to zero, and we solve for x, it will be undefined? I am sorry, I don't understand roots, but when you find the second derivative you can solve for x to determine that there is a point of inflection at x=0?

Comment: @Adsp: $f'$ and $f''$ are distinct functions. The roots of one do not "influence" the roots of the other.

You seem perturbed by the fact that $x$ such that $f'(x)=0$ is *not defined*. This is completely harmless, it just means that there is *no root*.

Comment: Ok. So from this, am I correct in saying that the function does not have any stationary points, (from the first derivative) but that it does have a point of inflection when x=0?

Comment: @Adsp: please read my answer, I worked for you.

Comment: Sorry Yves, what do you mean by having no roots, or single roots?

Comment: @Adsp: mh, zero and one root, maybe ? Is my English so bad ?

Comment: I think the OP didn't know what the word "root" means. A root of a function $g$ is a number $x$ such that $g(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The first derivative is defined for all values of x which means you can get a y value for any x value that you plug in. Don't confuse "undefined" and "has no roots". The fact that the second derivative is never zero simply means that the function does not have any stationary points (you can't draw a horizontal tangent line to the graph of the function). Also, if you take a closer look at the first derivative that you got, you will see that $\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2} > 0$. That means the slope is always positive which in turn means the function is always increasing. Though, that's probably beside the point. Long story short, you are correct in concluding that the function has no stationary points.

Comment: Hi Michael, when I solve the first derivative, I find that it is undefined. I set the derivative to equal zero and solve from there? (I get to a point where x=ln(0)). Or have I solved it incorrectly?

Comment: A function undefined for certain values of x in street language means that it doesn't work for those values of x. For example, the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined for $x=0$. You just can't plug it in because you can't divide by zero in mathematics. But, in general, yes, if you want to find stationary points, you set the first derivative equal to zero and try to find all x values that make the equation true. If there are such values, those are going to be your stationary points. If there are no such values, it means no stationary points exist.